# Dropdown list view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Has any one has the implemented drop-down view in their application. 
The drop-down view should behave like a search suggestion drop-down or a normal drop-down web component view having a button with the text-view field.
Or can any one guide me to such an article of the implementation is present on the web.
I have tried goggling but of no much help.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: Why don't you write your own?

Comment: I could use an open source implementation if some one has already done it, if not I will write it and share it with all here. I m just a bit scares of time, hence did not wanna to develop from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sample code to create dropdown view like html in your application.
http://code.google.com/p/dropdowndemo/downloads/list

The tutorial is here.
http://ameyashetti.wordpress.com/2010/09/26/drop-down-demo/

Answer (score 0):

you can use a UIPickerView as a Dropdown. Have you tried it?

Comment: I know about that option , the problem is it as in client requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tableView and use insert row at index path an make an array of index path then when you select a row, delete rows at indexpath. For the layout you can customize the way you want. I did it in my app it'very fluent.