# How to create dropdownlist without using UIPIckerviewcontroller in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I want to dropdownlist like listview at when i click the dropdown button and make the list have some contents.  then any content i select it will be text for the label any one help me.  Thanks Lot.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/vicpenap/VPPDropDown) control. It is a basic drop down selection menu that can be used to list options.

Comment: Pleas follow these links you will get done that you want i also tried these they work fine http://iphone-rahulvarma.blogspot.com/2011/06/customized-drop-down-list-in-iphone.html http://ameyashetti.wordpress.com/2010/09/26/drop-down-demo/ hope this helps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdown list view in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650525/dropdown-list-view-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pop-over to display list.In pop-over you can create tableview to display list of  items and when user selects any option, didSelectRowAtIndexPath will be called, from this method you can send the selected value and display in label.

Code in mainviewcontroller, where you want to display drop down.

```
if (m_OptionController !=nil)
        {
            [m_OptionController release]; m_OptionController = nil;

        }
        m_OptionController=[[OptionViewController alloc]init];
        [m_OptionController setTarget:self andSelector:@selector(displaySelectedOption:)];

        if(m_pPopOverController)
        {   
            [m_pPopOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            [m_pPopOverController release];
            m_pPopOverController=nil;
        }

        m_pPopOverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:m_OptionController];

        [m_pPopOverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(thePopOverFrame.size.width, thePopOverFrame.size.height) animated:NO];
        [m_pPopOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(theButton.frame.origin.x,0,40,40) inView:self
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

OptionViewController is a UIViewController which will contain UITableView.Populate UITableView with data(list of options).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if ([m_Target respondsToSelector:m_Selector]) {
                        [m_Target performSelector:m_Selector withObject:nil];
                    }
}
```

Do not forget to set target by calling this method, so when user selects any option, corresponding method in mainviewcontroller is called where you want selected value.

```
- (void)setTarget:(id)inTarget andSelector:(SEL)inSelector
{
    m_Target = inTarget;
    m_Selector = inSelector;
}
```